# C# JQuery, Load data in webform and pass it to another webform

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm making a "Ping" (ICMP) web application and I need to show the time results of the ping in a graph (I'm using shieldui). I'm really new to web development and so my knowledge on the frameworks is limited.

In "ping.aspx", I am loading a list of the servers I want to be able to ping. When I press a button labelled "ping", the web application will ping all the servers and then open a new window with a single graphic per each server.

It is working till the point of loading the graph in the new window

Here is my grafica.aspx file:

```
$(".pingAll").click(function () {
    primerClick = true;
    $("#txtLista option").each(function () {
        var valorSvr = $(this).val();
        //var container = $("#contenedorChart");
        //var grafics = container.find("div");
        //var idGrafics = grafics.length + 1;

        //container.append("<div id=shieldui-chart" + valorSvr + "></div>");

        refreshListaServidores(valorSvr)
    });
    //window.location.href = 'graficas.aspx';        
});


function refreshListaServidores(valorSvr) {

    $("#txtLista option").each(function () {
        var valorSvr = $(this).val();

        var container = $("#contenedorChart");
        var grafics = container.find("div");
        var idGrafics = grafics.length + 1;

        container.append("<div id=shieldui-chart" + valorSvr + "></div>");

    });

    lista = lista + "|" + valorSvr;
    var data = {
        vl: lista
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ping.aspx/valoresLista",
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            var resultado = result.d

            $.each(resultado, function (index, item) {
                var resultPing = { items: [] };
                var resultadoGrafica = { grafica: [null] };

                $.each(item, function (inde, ite) {
                    var valMs = ite.ms;
                    var valServer = ite.servers;
                    var txtData = "Servidor: " + valServer + " | " + "Dirección: " + ite.address + " | " +
                                  "Time to Live: " + ite.ttl + " | " + "Tamaño Buffer: " + ite.bufferSize + " | " +
                                  "Tiempo en ms: " + valMs + "\n";
                    resultadoGrafica.grafica.push(valMs);
                    resultPing.items.push(txtData);
                });

                $("#txtResultPing").val(resultPing.items);

                jQuery(function ($) {
                    $("div[id*='shieldui-chart" + valorSvr + "']").shieldChart({
                        axisX: {
                            axisType: 'linear',
                            ticksColor: 'yellow',
                            borderColor: 'yellow',
                            min: 1,
                            max: 40
                        },
                        theme: "dark",

                        primaryHeader: {
                            text: "Gráfico de: " + valorSvr
                        },
                        exportOptions: {
                            image: false,
                            print: false
                        },
                        dataSeries: [{
                            seriesType: "line",
                            collectionAlias: "Tiempos en ms",
                            data: resultadoGrafica.grafica
                        }]
                    });
                });
            });
        }, error: function (result, xhr, ajaOptions, throwError) {
            var vainaconvaina = result + xhr + ajaOptions + throwError;
        }
    });
}
```

and in back code, in c# I have

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<List<dataResult>> valoresLista(string vl)
    {
        dataResult dataRes = new dataResult();

        HttpContext.Current.Session["pingas"] = vl;

        Ping ping = new Ping();

        string contentLista = vl;
        string[] contentListaArray = contentLista.Split('|');
        List<dataResult> listaPing = new List<dataResult>();

        List<List<dataResult>> listaGral = new List<List<dataResult>>();

        foreach (string word in contentListaArray)
        {
            dataRes = new dataResult();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word.ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    listaPing = new List<dataResult>();
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
                    {
                        dataRes = new dataResult();
                        ping = new Ping();
                        PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(word);

                        if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                        {
                            dataRes.servers = Convert.ToString(word);
                            dataRes.address += Convert.ToString(pingreply.Address);
                            dataRes.ms += Convert.ToInt32(pingreply.RoundtripTime);
                            dataRes.ttl += Convert.ToInt32(pingreply.Options.Ttl);
                            dataRes.bufferSize += Convert.ToString(pingreply.Buffer.Length.ToString());
                            dataRes.errr += "Successful";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            dataRes.errr = Convert.ToString("Host de destino no disponible o inalcanzable");
                        }

                        listaPing.Add(dataRes);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    PingReply pingreply = ping.Send(word);
                    if (pingreply.Status == IPStatus.DestinationHostUnreachable || pingreply.Status == IPStatus.DestinationNetworkUnreachable || pingreply.Status == IPStatus.TimeExceeded || pingreply.Status == IPStatus.TtlExpired || pingreply.Status == IPStatus.Unknown)
                    {
                        string emailEnProceso = "Se le informa ";
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += "que el servidor " + vl;
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += "podría estar presentando fallos debido a que en el último minuto no estuvo respondiento las solicitudes de ping ";
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += "Tome las medidas necesarias. ";
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += "something";
                        emailEnProceso += Environment.NewLine;
                        emailEnProceso += "www.somethingelse.com";
                        string asunto = "Falla en el servidor " + vl;
                        enviarMail(emailEnProceso, asunto, "someEmail@gmail.com");


                        listaPing.Add(dataRes);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataRes.errr = Convert.ToString(err.Message);
                    }
                }

                listaGral.Add(listaPing);                   
            }
        }

        return listaGral;            
    }
```

I'm pretty sure this code is not that bad at all, but what I need to know is how to "move" the data from "ping.aspx" to "grafica.aspx".

Maybe I am really close, but in fact I don't really understand how to organize myself between to webforms.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from your code fragments, it seems to be ok. But it depends what data you get on the post success. Also you do not need to create a new chart instance on each request, you just can refresh the existing instance.
The whole app is needed though for detailed help.

Comment: in the post success of the jquery, I get a list a int values that represents the time of every ping event in milliseconds and I algo get a list of the severs that the application made the ping event. It should creat a chart for every server in the select box. I would like to take that data and pass it to the 2nd .aspx web page to build the chart. It works very well in a single .aspx webpage, but request says it should be in another web page. Thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it